# How to make Library in X86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-emulation

How to make your own library in X86 assembly Intel with your own functions.
I'm currently using invine.inc library,not that proficient at it

Comment: I think your question could elaborate a bit more, what you try to achieve. Maybe show some code you already got...

Comment: Depends on what you mean by “library.”  Do you mean a source file to include like `irvine.inc`?  Or rather a library in the sense of a collection of object files to be added to your program by the link editor (like a C library)?

Comment: Exactly just like Irvine which I can include in assembly and have call functions like Call writestring and some Nemonics like add.if you can help me out:))